# PSA - Nutrition proposal on Area 51

Tags: discussion

For all those interested in straight nutrition questions, there is now a nutrition proposal in Area 51. I would encourage people to follow it, as there have been a few sites (Cooking, Health, Fitness, etc) that have deemed straight nutrition questions to be off topic.

The link to the site is: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96697/nutrition

Comment: I followed, popped a couple of questions in, and used my votes.

Comment: Looks very useful and I hope it makes it to beta. Then we could sharpen what's on-topic regarding nutrition here (or remove it altogether). Can I assume asking an off-topic question is useful too as a demonstration of what the site shouldn't be about?

Comment: And, for those viewing this from the future, the proposal has since been deleted.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original notification/proposal was closed without making it to beta.